# How to open a new PWA window from inside the PWA?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to open a new window of my PWA application inside of it. But when I click on the anchor a new chrome tab is open.

Anyone can help me to open two instances of my PWA application?

An example of it is outlook, where you can open a new window of the application to write your email.

Thanks

Comment: How about iframes?

Comment: Today I figure it out what to do. You need to open the windows using the window.open function...

Comment: Sorry that you have a negative score from this question, I don't know why. It has helped me and thanks for posting the answer as well

Comment: I found a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563889/how-can-i-make-a-button-which-opens-a-new-instance-of-my-web-app but the answer on this page is NOT AN ANSWER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was very easy, I just need to open the new window using the `window.open`, and not using the anchor tag (A).

Documentation about this function:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Window/open

For this to work, you have to pass `width` and `height` attributes, I couldn't find any documentation for that requirement, but it just works, example:

```js
window.open('https://my.app.domain/route.to/something', null, 'width=600,height=400');
```

Comment: Here it still opens in a new chrome tab, even with window.open. Anything else needs to be set up?

Comment: It still opens the window with an address bar, rather than the frameless window of the original pwa.

Comment: I accidentally down voted this amazing answer and now I cannot fix it.  I am so sorry.  This was an amazing answer that I had spent hours searching for.  I will try to upvote tomorrow.

Comment: unfortunately this answer only will open ONE other instance of the web app. If you want to open multiple windows , this will not work.  Anyone have an answer?

Comment: The second parameter `target` can be any string, so it will open a new window for any new values there, and show the existing window if it has already been used.

Answer (score 1):

```
function newWindow() {
window.open("https://WEBADRESS/index.html","_blank","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=900, height=700");
}
```

Feel free to arrange the settings as you like.
Found the answer on this site.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_openallwindow

Unfortunately they have an error in their code.  I fixed it.