# How can I make a button which opens a new instance of my web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have made a progressive web app that installs from the browser and works offline.
[ http://taiwamaker.netlify.app ]

I want to make a button in the main navigation which when clicked will open a new app window.
I don't want to open the window in a chrome tab

On my computer (linux/gnome) I can right click on the webapp icon from my launcher and there is an option to open a new app window.  This is fine but I want to make a button inside of the app which does this.

I have found that this option was not available on my windows machine from the windows taskbar/panel.

I have mostly stuck with Jquery and Javascript solutions for this page.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have made the following script which opens in new tab or new browser window.  But I want to open a new instance of the web app.

```
function newWindow() {
  window.open(window.location.href);

}


function newWindow() {
 
  window.open("https://your-web-app-url.com", "_blank", "width=800,height=600");

}
```

Comment: How you have deployed your WebApp in Azure?What is the`framework and version` you are using ?

Comment: sorry. I dont know how those tags got in there.  I have removed azure

Comment: I found a duplicate question but it does not have a solution.  It has been answered with a green check but it is not an answer. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597919/how-to-open-a-new-pwa-window-from-inside-the-pwa

Comment: I believe that the answer most likely lies in serviceWorker.js code But I am lost as to how to implement this.

Comment: found the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597919/how-to-open-a-new-pwa-window-from-inside-the-pwa